# Why the package version contains "random" additional information?

Tags: c#, version, nuget-package

I have created a very simple console application in .NET 8 to illustrate the problem I encounter. Simply ran `dotnet new console` and added a "Version" element in the .csproj, so it contains:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <Version>1.2.3-alpha</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Now I want to programmatically get the package version recorded in Version element. I saw on another stackoverflow thread that the code to do so is:

```cs
using System.Reflection;

var version = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
    .GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()
    .InformationalVersion;

Console.WriteLine(version);
```

But when I run this, instead of getting `1.2.3-alpha` as expected, I get `1.2.3-alpha+9d1761b41223159ec45d7d492e08820f706d7ad1`.

How can I get only the package version without this extra "random" information ?

Edit: The code above is just to illustrate the situation. In real life the code getting the package version of the **entry** assembly is executed in a library. So adding `IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion` is not a viable solution because it will require to update every library client.

How can I get only the package version without this extra "random" information and without having to add an attribute in the entry project ?

Comment: You need to add `IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion` to every project whose informational version is being set. You can set it for all projects in a solution using `Directory.props`

Comment: I have reformulated the question more concisely here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77562609/how-to-get-package-version-in-net-8-without-having-to-add-includesourcerevision