# How to get package version in .NET 8 without having to add IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion attribute in the entry assembly?

Tags: c#, package, nuget, .net-8.0

I have developed a nuget package in which I need to obtain the package version of the entry assembly. So far, I used this method to get the version:

```cs
using System.Reflection;

var version = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
    .GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()
    .InformationalVersion;

Console.WriteLine(version);
```

It was working well and was returning only the package version of the entry assembly until now. But there was a [breaking change in `InformationalVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/8.0/source-link) and now the SourceRevisionId is appended to InformationalVersion. For instance, instead of getting `1.2.3-alpha` as expected, I get `1.2.3-alpha+9d1761b41223159ec45d7d492e08820f706d7ad1`.

I know it is possible to add `<IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>false</IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>` in the csproj of the entry assembly as suggested here : [FileVersionInfo.ProductVersion suddenly contains git commit hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77050814/fileversioninfo-productversion-suddenly-contains-git-commit-hash)

But this solution is not suitable to me because my package is used by multiple clients and I don't want to have to modify all of them. I need a way to get only the package version without the added SourceRevisionId.

Is there a proper way to do this or do the only solution is to truncate the string after the "+" sign ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, modifying the .csproj is the only way to resolve the git hash being assigned to the assembly version. As a workaround, you could simply change your code to retrieve the version to include the following:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
var version = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
    .GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()
    .InformationalVersion;

version = version.Split("+").First();
Console.WriteLine(version);
```

The above code will split off the git hash from the version and grab just the first part of the string after the "+".

However, I do question why you can't change the .csproj - you should be able to change that and then push out the updated package to your clients without any manual update of each client.

Comment: Changing the csproj of the nuget package has no effect on InformationalVersion because it is called on the **entry** assembly. So the attribute has to be set in the entry assembly and not the package assembly.